# How do I add a Unicode search to the JavaScript console of a desktop, mobile, or game console browser?

Tags: javascript, unicode, bookmarklet

It would be nice if I could search for the Unicode escape sequence of a particular character using the browser JavaScript console or via a bookmarklet. Is there any way to easily do this?

Comment: Which browser are you talking about?

Comment: @MoonSire Any browser with a JavaScript command line: [desktop](http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/25-dev-tool-secrets/), [mobile](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/08/14/debugging-javascript-on-android-and-ios/), or [game console](http://alistapart.com/article/testing-websites-in-game-console-browsers)

Comment: Ah ok, now I understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function which can be run from the console or saved as a bookmarklet to generate a Unicode lookup table:

```
function Unicode()
  {
  var i = 0, unicode = {}, zero_padding = "0000", max = 9999;
  //Loop through code points
  while (i < max) {
    //Convert decimal to hex value, find the character, then pad zeroes to the codepoint
    unicode[String.fromCharCode(parseInt(i, 16))] = ("u" + zero_padding + i).substr(-4);
    i = i + 1;
    }

  //Replace this function with the resulting lookup table
  Unicode = unicode;
  }

//Usage
Unicode();
Unicode["%"];
```